# Math Formatting in native Android? MathView library not working

Tags: java, android, math, webview, mathjax

I am creating a quiz app which includes some chemical and mathematical equations. I had a previous version that used a `WebView` and `jqmath` library to display the files. That version was very inefficient and was dead slow in old android phones (2 year old ones). I scraped that thing and started the quiz page again.

I have a `TabLayout` and a `CardView`. `TabLayout` is used to switch between the questions and `CardView` is used to display the questions. But I have the database setup in such a way that if two `$$` occur in a string then use `jqmath` to format the string.

For eg : if the json is like this `"Qno":5,"Question":"If the point represented by the complex number iz is rotated about the origin through the angle $$\u03c0\/2$$ in the counter clockwise direction then the complex number representing the new position is:","Option1":"iz","Option2":"-iz","Option3":"-z","Option4":"z","Correct":"C"`

then the output is[image: Sample Output]

I can take care of the `$$` symbol with some java functions but I have no idea how to make the expression (pi divide by 2) appear as should be. When I used `jqmath` my output was something like this

[image: Wanted Output]

How to achieve this in native android using java without affecting my existing code...??

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the comments I used [this library](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView). But this is not working properly. Sometimes it is rendering correctly sometimes not.

For Eg: Correct Rendering[image: Correct]

Wrong Rendering [image: Wrong]

The `TextView` in the top is just a normal `TextView` that is showing the text that is being displayed. `WebView` is the set of text that is displayed below that.

What is wrong? Any help is appreciated

Comment: There is no native TeX formatting class for Android

Comment: check this library: https://github.com/kexanie/MathView

Comment: take a look at HTML class in android though it is not so powerful to parse but may help to achieve this. you can  use it like textView.setText(HTML.parse("html code here"));

Comment: @Rahil2952 I tried that library and it is working but the problem it is inefficient... It is giving the same results that I got when I was working with `WebView`